# Is there a way to "fix" cheap aftermarket charger with poor grounding?

Tags: laptop, charging, charger, ground

I bought a cheap aftermarket charger for one of my laptops and when I'm using it while plugged in, the touchpad is stuttering while it doesn't when the charger is unplugged. I looked around and I surmised I have the same issue as here https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/erratic-touchpad-when-AC-charger-is-plugged/td-p/3795630 except that my laptop does not have a metal body that I can place my palms on.

So I want to know if there's any way to sort of "fix" the charger or should I just toss it? I don't like waste so I'd rather fix it than tossing it and buying another one.

Comment: Sounds like one of those that's only [I'm arm-waving a bit here] half-rectified, so rather than taking the full +ve to -ve sweep & ironing that into a 'flat' signal, you're getting only the top half of the voltage every time round, so you get DC in pulses. Characteristic of it upsetting a touch screen/trackpad. Bin it.

Comment: You already have an answer, but the question you always have to ask about accessories is simple: Is the “cheap” charger more valuable than the device it is charging? Of course many charger makers exploit this concept to sell overpriced chargers, but you should always find a reputable brand if not an official OEM replacement. If your laptop blows up you will not suddenly go, “Well! At least my $10 charger still works!”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "cheap" charger is faulty, you dont know if it will fail catastrophically and damage your laptop.  It is far better to replace it with a quality charger.

Think of it this way:  Its far cheaper to buy a new expensive charger than it is to buy a new expensive laptop.